# Не удается создать класс в NetBeans 12.2

Tags: java, классы, netbeans, freemarker

Не могу создать класс в IDE NetBeans 12.2. При нажатии "Finish" ничего не происходит. В качестве ошибки выдает следующее:freemarker/template/TemplateException. Раньше этого не было. Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобным?  [image: Окно создания класса][1]]

Comment: с высокой вероятностью ваша проблема связана с темной темой.

Comment: Спасибо, Вы хоть и не напрямую, но помогли мне. После смены темы на белую IDE выкинуло сообщение, что не может работать с установленным Hibernate :). Теперь все работает, но Hibernate мой отрубился)

Comment: боюсь, что просто отключение темной темы вам не поможет. тут пахнет переустановкой нетбинса с полным удалением всех параметров

Comment: Все работает, просто отключил криво установленный плагин для работы с Hibernate, он и не понадобился по итогу.